# spark hive job keep failing with OutOfMemory: java heap space error

Tags: apache-spark, hive, out-of-memory

When I run hive job, this failure appeared in the same stage and task.

```
16/08/29 03:45:27 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 296.1 in stage 10.0 (TID 22783, lvshdc2dn0501.lvs.paypal.com): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeInMemorySorter.expandPointerArray(UnsafeInMemorySorter.java:115)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeInMemorySorter.insertRecord(UnsafeInMemorySorter.java:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeKVExternalSorter.<init>(UnsafeKVExternalSorter.java:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeFixedWidthAggregationMap.destructAndCreateExternalSorter(UnsafeFixedWidthAggregationMap.java:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.switchToSortBasedAggregation(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:435)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.processInputs(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.start(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$aggregate$TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$$executePartition$1(TungstenAggregate.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsWithPreparationRDD.compute(MapPartitionsWithPreparationRDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsWithPreparationRDD.compute(MapPartitionsWithPreparationRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I was going to join two table, and make some count by group of the result, and at last, I'll get the count result. Codes like this:

```
override def monitor(sqlContext: SQLContext, date: String) = {
  sqlContext.setConf("hive.map.aggr", "true")
  sqlContext.setConf("hive.groupby.skewindata", "true")
  //get data
  val targetDF = getLinked(date, sqlContext)
  //count what we need
  getTargetMap(sqlContext, targetDF)

}

def getLinked(date: String, sqlContext: SQLContext): DataFrame = {
  val l = sqlContext.read.parquet(get_l_path(date)).select("id").distinct()
  val a = sqlContext.read.parquet(get_a_path(date)).select("cust_id", "seg")
  targetLinkedEbay.registerTempTable("et")
  accountAttr.registerTempTable("acct")

  sqlContext.sql(
  """
    |select a.seg as seg
    | a.id as id
    |from
    | acct a join et e on a.cust_id=e.pp_id
  """.stripMargin)
}

def getTargetMap(sqlContext: SQLContext, targetDF: DataFrame): Map[String, String] = {
  val tmpTable = "tmp"
  targetDF.registerTempTable(tmpTable)
  sqlContext.sql(
  s"""
    |select
    | seg, count(distinct id)
    |from
    | $tmpTable
    |group by
    | seg
  """.stripMargin).collect()
  .foldLeft(Map[String, String]())((map, row)=>map + (row.getString(0)->row.get(1).toString))
}
```

basically, there're two process:Firstly, we make a join of table l and a, we abstract id, and seg from table a, whose id exist in table l. Secondly, after getting (id, seg) table (we called target later). We count distinct id in same seg, so we use count and group by on target table.

There're around 2 billion records in the target table, and only 6 different seg, and of course, there's data skew that one type seg has more than half records.

We used hive on spark. The code is in scala, and we submit the job to spark by spark's submit shell script. I found that hive.groupby.skewindata parameter may be helpful, so I set it true by sqlContext.setConf, but I don't know whether it works?

Comment: Some code to show?

Comment: Sorry, I was hurry to submit the question and was going to add other details later.